# Image button not responding with new activity

Tags: android

i have some image buttons in my main layout, and some of them are made to start new activities but when i install the app in my phone the image buttons do not make nothing. please help.

heres my code in main activity

```
 ImageButton botondiseno = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Botondiseno);
    botondiseno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and my layout

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Botondiseno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/accept"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/botondisenointeriores" />
```

Comment: Donno where is your issue. I've tried and it on it works. 
What is the Android version of your test device?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use AppCompatImageButton instead of just ImageButton

Like,

```
 AppCompatImageButton botondiseno = (AppCompatImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Botondiseno);
botondiseno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe try setting the src to your drawable instead of using srcCompat in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see your button? Set the "src" attribute of your ImageButton to make it visible:

```
android:src="@drawable/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran ur code at new proj and its working fine, the ImageButton botondiseno  is working fine and change the activity to Main2Activity. the only change i made to modify the code,i changed at the .xml the line:
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/botondisenointeriores"
to:
app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_own"
and this because i dont have that drawable.

it looks like there is something else in ur code that is not working, maybe u can post all of it.
maybe u should try to Rebuild ur project